# Reference cell content

Tags: vba

I am pulling the file names from a folder into my workbook using this

```
    Sub C_Get_file_names_from_TGRE_M1()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFolder = oFSO.getfolder("C:\Users\ferna\Downloads\")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name

    i = i + 1

Next oFile

End Sub
```

Now instead of referencing the folder directly I want to write the folder path in a cell like D5 and reference that cell in my code. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the hardcoded file path with a range reference to your cell

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set oFolder = oFSO.getfolder(ws.Range("D5").Value)
```

Comment: Accept solution then :)